# CSS3, div not aligned properly after rotation

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, rotation

I am in front of a mystery:  I have a box, the css defines the width of each side.
I use links to rotate the box, adding a class to show each side.
The link just clears the classes of the box, and adds one of the following class:

```
.show-front {
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.show-back {
   transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.show-left {
   transform: rotateY(-270deg);
}

.show-right {
   transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 }
```

However, depending on the side in front, the alignment of the div is not the same.
I isolated my problem and created a codepen at the following location: http://codepen.io/3MO/pen/XpwYBB

I check the dimensions and coordinates of each side brought to front, I cannot see the problem. What do I miss?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divs don't fit inside the parrent.

You forgot the additional `border-width` on your `boxSide` divs.
Your `#mainBox` should have `width: 1102px;`.

Comment: I don't understand : for every border I add, I declare "1px solid". Plus, on #mainBox, I do add width:1102, it's the variable $mainDivWidth. (I corrected, I forgot to put it to 1102 instead of 1100 when I isolated the problem for CodePen, but event with 1102 the problem remains.)

Comment: I just tested, with width:1102 and boxSide border-width:1px, the problem remains.

Comment: Ok I got it, you are right: boxSide width needs to be 2 px less than mainBox. I am so stupid! Thanks !!!